# In MYSQL while adding the primary key column to an existing table I am getting error 1795(hy000)

Tags: mysql, primary-key, full-text-indexing

I am new to this platform so if I make any mistake forgive me.

In MYSQL 8.0, I am trying to add primary key by using the following command,

```
ALTER TABLE TELECOM_NUMBER ADD pk_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

> ERROR 1795 (HY000): InnoDB presently supports one FULLTEXT index creation at a time

what could be the solution

I have tried this

```
ALTER TABLE TELECOM_NUMBER ADD pk_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, ALGORITHM=COPY;
```

but got the following error

> ERROR 1264 (22003): Out of range value for column 'columns' at row 167

this is my existing table

```
CREATE TABLE `TELECOM_NUMBER` (
  `CONTACT_MECH_ID` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `COUNTRY_CODE` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `MOBILE_NUMBER` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `AREA_CODE` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `CONTACT_NUMBER` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ASK_FOR_NAME` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `LAST_UPDATED_STAMP` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `LAST_UPDATED_TX_STAMP` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `CREATED_STAMP` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `CREATED_TX_STAMP` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `INX_TELECOM` (`CONTACT_MECH_ID`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `TELECOM_NUMBER_FT` (`CONTACT_NUMBER`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `TELECOM_NUMBER_FTS` (`CONTACT_NUMBER`,`MOBILE_NUMBER`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Update:
this solution worked but still testing that everything is fine.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43820504/10862513

changing the storage engine .

Comment: Have you seen [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28666643/what-does-the-mysql-5-6-error-innodb-presently-supports-one-fulltext-index-crea) ?

Comment: this answer worke https://stackoverflow.com/a/43820504/10862513

Answer (score 1):

Try to write Primary Key before AUTO_INCREMENT like below:

```
ALTER TABLE TELECOM_NUMBER ADD pk_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the column first and then add the constraint using `ADD CONSTRAINT` command. Do it as follows: -

1) `ALTER TABLE TELECOM_NUMBER ADD pk_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;`

2) `ALTER TABLE TELECOM_NUMBER ADD CONSTRAINT primary_key_constraint_name PRIMARY KEY (pk_id);`

Hope it helps.

Comment: got this error                                                                                                    ERROR 1075 (42000): Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key