# Why in mariadb 10.6.11 does copy to tmp table occur when adding a field to the end of a table with default value NULL?

Tags: mariadb

There are two large tables (> 10GB). When adding a field to one of them to the end of the table, copy to tmp table happens, when adding a field to the other one, it happens immediately altering table - you can see it in phpmyadmin in the state tab, state column. Why does this happen? As far as I know, in later versions of mysql and mariadb such queries should be executed without copying data to a temporary table. Both tables are innodb. Example query

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable` ADD `last_field` VARCHAR(511) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `last_field_now`
```

Comment: It may depend on the original table structure. Do the two tables have the same sschema?

Answer (score 2):

MariaDB has multiple algorithms for the `ALTER TABLE`-command.

Check for the [limitations](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/instant-add-column-for-innodb/) for the `INSTANT` alter Algorithm and see if these apply to your table.

> - If the table contains a hidden FTS_DOC_ID column due to a FULLTEXT    INDEX, then instant ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN will not be possible.
> - InnoDB data files after instant ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN cannot be    imported to older versions of MariaDB or MySQL without first
>   being    rebuilt.
> - After using Instant ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN, any table-rebuilding    operation such as ALTER TABLE … FORCE will
>   incorporate    instantaneously added columns into the main table body.
> - Instant ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN is not available for    ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED.

Comment: yes, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28666643/what-does-the-mysql-5-6-error-innodb-presently-supports-one-fulltext-index-crea - here the user suggests deleting the fulltext index and then adding it back. But when I try to add a full-text index again, the site freezes, apparently the table is locked. Is it possible to re-add a fulltext index without locking the table?